# Python: Getting value from calling function

Tags: python

In Python, is there a simple way for an invoked function to get a value from the calling function/class ? I'm not sure if I'm phrasing that right, but I'm trying to do something like this:

```
class MainSection(object):
    def function(self):
        self.var = 47  # arbitrary variable 
        self.secondaryObject = secondClass()  # Create object of second class
        self.secondaryObject.secondFunction(3)  # call function in that object
```

and

```
class secondClass(object):
    def secondFunction(self, input)
        output = input + self.var  # calculate value based on function parameter AND variable from calling function
        return output
        #Access self.var from MainSection
```

This might be my lack of knowledge about Python, but I'm having a hard time finding a clear answer here. Is the best way to do that just passing the variable I want in as another second parameter to the second class?
These are in separate files, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to access `self.var` from the second function? You can just pass self.var when calling it like this: `self.secondaryObject.secondFunction(self.var)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the best way to do that just passing the variable I want in as another second parameter to the second class?

Yes, especially if there's only a transient relationship between the objects:

```
class secondClass(object):
    def secondFunction(self, input, var_from_caller)
        output = input + var_from_caller  # calculate value based on function parameter AND variable from calling function
        return output
```

You can even pass around the whole object if you like:

```
class secondClass(object):
    def secondFunction(self, input, calling_object)
        output = input + calling_object.var  # calculate value based on function parameter AND variable from calling function
        return output
```

If the relationship is more permanent, you could consider storing references to the related objects in instance variables:

```
class MainSection(object):
    def function(self):
        self.var = 47  # arbitrary variable 
        self.secondaryObject = secondClass(self)  # Create object of second class
        self.secondaryObject.secondFunction(3)  # call function in that object

...
class secondClass(object):
    def __init__(self, my_friend):
        self.related_object = my_friend

    def secondFunction(self, input)
        output = input + self.related_object.var  # calculate value based on function parameter AND variable from calling function
        return output
        #Access self.var from MainSection
```

Comment: Nice answer, also consider adding my example from my comment as well. Goes along with what he's asking and what you're saying as well

Comment: @Jaba sure, I added an example for just passing around the variable too. Thanks for the feedback.